# Can not get properties from soup ui context

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have 2 groovy scripts inside a testsuite in one groovy script i am doing the following step

```
context.setProperty( "values", list );
context.setProperty( "index", 0 );

log.info("Values " + context.getProperty( "values" ))
log.info("Index " + context.getProperty( "index" ))

Log file has: 
Tue Mar 13 09:33:50 CDT 2012:INFO:Values [9019439!2009-04-30T00:00:00, 9021279!2009-02-28T00:00:00, 9021295!2009-03-01T00:00:00, 9021567!2009-01-01T00:00:00]
Tue Mar 13 09:33:50 CDT 2012:INFO:Index 0
```

Now in another groovy script I am performing

```
def values = context.getProperty( "values" );
def index = context.getProperty( "index" );

log.info( "Values " + values );
log.info( "Index " + index);
```

I am getting back null values and I dont understand why. I have done this before in the past and it worked just fine.

Comment: Hmm... are the test steps running in the order in which you listed them? In order words, is the step with context.setProperty() running before the step with context.getProperty()? I does seem like you're doing everything right.

Comment: You can only have steps inside the test case, but on the suite level. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your groovy scripts are in the same test suite but Are they in the same tescase ? 
Because the context is lost when the test ends so you can't reuse your properties like that.
If you want to run your scripts together, you need to use the method run of your teststep instance